# Instrumented test: could not find dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, instrumented-test

I'm trying to launch a simple instrumented test on my project, but something gone wrong. This is my simple test class (the default one):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        assertEquals("com.mypackage.a123myappkotlin", appContext.packageName)
    }
}
```

but when i try launch it, i obtain this error:

```
Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' that satisfies the version constraints: 
Dependency path '123myappkotlin:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
Dependency path '123myappkotlin:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.14.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0'
Dependency path '123myappkotlin:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
Dependency path '123myappkotlin:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0' --> 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
Constraint path '123myappkotlin:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.12.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
Constraint path '123myappkotlin:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.12.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
```

this is my relative app gradle for the dependency that appears on this error

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$logger_interception_version"
androidTestImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$logger_interception_version"
testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$logger_interception_version"

androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.14.0'

implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
```

where version values are:

```
ext.logger_interception_version = '3.12.0'
ext.retrofit_version = '2.4.0'
```

what's wrong?

Comment: What is `logger_interception_version` variable value?

Comment: @Ircover i've edited my question

Comment: Versions of `okhttp3:logging-interceptor` and `okhttp3:mockwebserver` dependencies are different. Did you try to make them same?

Comment: Ok, now it works. But why i have that fail else if i don't use that dependencies into my test class?